# Achieve the crispiness of fried potatoes using baking

Tags: baking, frying, potatoes, french-fries

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I bake normally fried foods?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/14600/how-can-i-bake-normally-fried-foods)

I usually cut my potatoes into sticks that are slightly bigger than your generic frozen fries. I've tried baking the sticks with low temperature (350) / long duration and with high heat (425) / short duration. I still can't achieve the crispy on the outside but moist, soft, and not dry on the inside. The results are either mushy or crispy but dry and unchewable.
 I tried baking the sticks with a bit of oil, or a bit of oil mixed with butter to get some browning going, but that didn't achieve the same results.

**Question:** What are some of the cooking techniques involved to produce quality baked potato sticks to make them taste similar to fried potatoes (French fries)?

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe it's possible? For example, have you had baked fries with the desired consistency before?